# Unity3d: Create mp4 video from texture frames

Tags: unity-game-engine, video

I've searched a lot in Google and Stack overflow and it seems there are a lot of answers but all of them seems complicated and rely on a huge third-party libraries.

What's the fast way to create and save mp4(or any other video type) video from Texture frames in Unity3d?

Comment: Unity does not have such a functionality so you either have to use a library or implement it yourself.

Comment: Found this in the assets store that can record from a texture and from many other sources as well. https://docs.natml.ai/natcorder/